# Protractor not go to next line after click from dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor

I am using protractor to select item from dropdown. The dropdown element will only appear when click on dropdown button.

Because of the id keep on changing, i use element.all to getText and use if condition to compare if the list is same with my value, to click on the item.

```
<div class="ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformPanel ng-tns-c4-15 mat-select-panel mat-primary ng-star-inserted" style="transform-origin: 50% 127.5px 0px; font-size: 14px; opacity: 1; min-width: calc(100% + 32px); transform: scaleY(1);">
            <!---->
            <mat-option _ngcontent-c20="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-59" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                <!---->
                <span class="mat-option-text"> Cik </span>
                <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option _ngcontent-c20="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-60" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                <!---->
                <span class="mat-option-text"> Dato' </span>
                <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option _ngcontent-c20="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-61" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
                <!---->
                <span class="mat-option-text"> Dato Paduka </span>
                <div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
            </mat-option>
```

How I am trying to do is as below:

```
function Select(title){
    element(by.name("title")).click().then(function(){
        browser.sleep(1000)
    })
    element.all(by.tagName("mat-option")).each(function(item){
        item.getAttribute("id").getText().then(function(z){
            if(z==title){
                item.click().then(function(){
                    console.log("success select title");
                    })
                }       
            })
        });
```

My problem is, after click on the selection, protractor returns to top and try to search for the element again because i am using each function(at this point it will fail to search the element as the dropdown is already closed). It did not go to the next function to proceed for other fields.

Below is the error that i get after it select successfully:

```
Failed: The element reference of <mat-option id="mat-option-575" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Is there any other way i can continue without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the loop purely to find and click on the correct option. If that is the case then I don't think there is any need to loop at all. In fact by looping in this way you may miss an exception if the title you expect to be there is not present as it simply won't click on anything.

If I've understood correct you can try simply locating the element and clicking on it but if I've missed some constraint let me know.

```
function Select(title) {

    element(by.name("title")).click().then(function () {
        browser.sleep(1000);
        element(by.xpath(`//mat-option[text()='${title}']`)).click()
            .then(function () {
                console.log(`Clicked option containing ${title}`);
            })
        //alternate locator to try
        // element(by.xpath(`//mat-option/span[text()='${title}']/parent::mat-option`))
    })
};
```

Comment: I think your method might work. But it fails to find the element by xpath.

Can you advise on how it should be written if using css locator?

I only know how to put the locator but not sure how to put the checking within the locator for the element to compare with my value.

Comment: I tried to change it like this but still cannot find locator:
 element(by.css("mat-option=[text()='${title}']")).click()

Comment: @hafizan I'll need to look up the exact syntax for css but in the meantime you could try `element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option',title).click()`

Comment: @hafizan no problem. Just be aware that `cssContainingText` checks if text **contains** a string as opposed to **is** a string. Which means if you have two options for `chief officer` and just `chief` using `containingText('mat-option','chief')` will find whichever one of those options comes first

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function.

```
async function Select(title){
    await browser.sleep(1000);
    await element(by.name("title")).click();
    await browser.sleep(1000);
    const ele = element.all(by.css('div>mat-option>span.mat-option-text'));
    for(i=0;i< ele.count();i++){
       if(await ele.get(i).getText() === title){
            await browser.sleep(1000);
             await ele.get(i).click();
             await browser.sleep(1000);
             break;
        }
     }
  }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi. thanks for response. I tried your solution but it seems cannot find the attribute title and just skips and go to next step.

Comment: @hafizan Can you share me the code how you implemented the solution

Comment: function Select(title){
  element(by.name("title")).click().then(function(){
   browser.sleep(1000)
  })
  
  
   browser.sleep(1000);
     const ele = element.all(by.css('div>mat-option>span.mat-option-text'));
     for(i=0;i< ele.count();i++){
        if(ele.get(i).getText() === title){
              browser.sleep(1000);
              ele.get(i).click();
              browser.sleep(1000);
              break;
         }
      }
 }

Comment: I think there is a problem with promise chaining. Try `async/await`. Refer updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for my case. Thanks to @DublinDev :)

```
function Select(title) {

    element(by.name("title")).click().then(function () {
        browser.sleep(1000);
        element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option',title)).click().then(function () {
                console.log("click title");
            })
    })
};
```